# Как сократить количество символов в числе Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть переменная типа **float** и у него есть свое значение. Допустим оно будет **1,340,000**. Это число нужно вывести в **Unity** через объект текста в формате **1.34 М (Миллион)**, то-есть сократить число и при этом, чтобы оставалось 2 знака после запятой. Как это реализовать? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: может делением?

Comment: Мне нужно лишние числа после запятой убрать

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать деление на `1e6` с последующим вызовом `ToString` и указанием желаемой маски форматтера числа `#.##`, что соответсвует двум знакам после после разделителя целой и дробной части

```
(1234567/1e6).ToString("#.## M");
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/OKFhs8